# How to run ripple v2 on local

Tags: node.js, ripple, rippled

I downloaded the source code of `rippled-historical-database` on github,
 https://github.com/ripple/rippled-historical-database

but I don’t know how to run it on locally. **Can I build my own Ripple Data API v2 service ?**

I tried to run the test file under the test path locally, and got the following error:

```
期望:[null]
实际 :{"errno":-61,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":7117}
<点击查看差异>

    at Request._callback (test/test.accounts.js:19:14)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:432:9)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:84:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The repository you've been downloaded is but a API reference repo to the full history node.

In order to run a full history node you'd need `10TB+` of disk space and enormously good connection to the internet.

Are you sure about that?

Otherwise, if you're trying to access a full history node using `The Ripple Data API v2`, it is stated in the repo you've specified as below:

> Ripple provides a live instance of the Data API with as complete a
> transaction record as possible at the following address:
>
> https://data.ripple.com
>
> You can run a historical database yourself, but we don’t recommend it
> because of the complexity involved. If your use case requires that you
> run a historical database, contact Ripple Technical Services for
> information about how to set it up.

If you wanna try it out online. Do so by visiting:
https://xrpl.org/data-api-v2-tool.html#get-ledger

Comment: Im trying to connect to my own Ripple network, not Ripple’s public network .

Comment: @Rihaty oh i misunderstood then. for that i have no experience. have you fiddled around with the configs? https://github.com/ripple/rippled-historical-database/blob/master/config/config.json.example